# Google Map not displaying correctly after adding a jquery mobile panel

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

The map was displaying properly before the addition of the `panel`. Now as soon as I add a `panel div` on the page the map displays just like this:

[image]

It is just cluttered on the top portion leaving a wide space below. The button on the top left corner of the image is used to open the panel which opens fine. Sorry for the patchy image work.

**The html is below:**

```
<body>

    <div data-role="page" id="map-page" data-url="map-page">

        <div data-role="panel" id="mypanel">
            <!-- This is the problematic panel-->
        </div><!-- /panel -->

        <div data-role="header">
            <a href="#mypanel" data-role="button" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext">Choose Station</a>
            <h1>The Header</h1>

            <a href="index.html" data-ajax="false" data-role="button" data-icon="refresh" data-iconpos="notext">Refresh</a>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content" id="map-canvas"> <!--Div for map display.-->
        </div><!-- /content -->

        <div data-role="footer" data-id="myfooter" class="ui-bar" data-position="fixed">
            <h4>© 2013</h4>
        </div><!-- /footer -->

    </div><!-- /page -->
</body>
```

**My custom css**

```
html { height: 100% }

body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }

#map-page, #map-canvas { height: 100% }
```

Otherwise I am using default `jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css`. I probably know it might well be because of css, but could not figure out.

Comment: Try putting map canvas inside content div. other words, leave content div untouched.

Comment: You mean like this `<div data-role="content"><div id="map-canvas">       </div></div>`. The map is not displayed at all in this case.

Comment: Then you need to show map on `pageshow`, when contents div's height is set.

Comment: All my logic to create the map and markers are inside `pageinit`. Can you provide a quick hint how to do that?

Comment: Try replacing `pageinit` with `pageshow` and bind it to `#map-page`. `$(document).on('pageshow', '#map-page', function ()`.

Comment: It did not make any difference. I am still getting the map like in the image I posted.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34021/discussion-between-omar-and-suyesh)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to change your custom **`CSS`**. In this working example I have used your HTML page and modified its CSS. You main problem here is not panel at least not directly. Panel height will cause page content div to miss behave, it can be fix with a **`CSS`** used below.

This is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/7kGdE/105/

#### CSS :

```
#map-canvas {
    padding: 0;
    position : absolute !important; 
    top : 40px !important;  
    right : 0; 
    bottom : 40px !important;  
    left : 0 !important;     
}
```

This solution is also described **[HERE](http://www.gajotres.net/using-google-maps-javascript-api-v3-with-jquery-mobile/)**.

Comment: Yes indeed. Perfectly working. Thanks for the neat piece of code. And +1 for your nice informative blog.

Comment: Yes, it worked.
I used it with modifying top:0px; and bottom:0px; for full screen display.
Thanks @Gajotres